# External IP address appears instead of Domain Name

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am running a website in Google Compute Engine and configured a DNS zone and an A record to point to the IP address where my web-server runs. In my domain registrar (GoDaddy), I changed name-servers to point to Google name servers.

I can browse to the website without issues, but it show the IP address of the server instead of domain name. How can I change that to show domain name such as www.example.com instead?

Comment: You should add where it shows the IP address.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give me more detail. The IP address is listed throughout Google Cloud.

Comment: There are many places to see domain names and IP addresses, is it in a browser, as user or as as admin, when you ping etc.

Comment: How can I get my domain name to replace the IP address that shows in the browser. I createf A, AAA and CNAME records to point my domain to my app. When I access my wordpress page my external IP address displays. I can only access the page by entering the external IP address. If I enter the domain name I get an error "The page URL is not listed in the directory." Please give me instructions on how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe someone who with a good amount of Google Compute experience can guess what you mean, but I am just getting confused.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226379/ip-address-is-shown-instead-of-domain-name-in-the-browser it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I have a website hosted in GCE running under a Linux machine Apache Server. I created an A record in my DNS pointing to the external IP address of the server. When I access the link the subdomain name is not replaced by the IP. I do not believe your issue is particularly related to Compute Engine.

Particularly if you are using WordPress you will need to change some configuration files as stated in

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/browser-displaying-ip-instead-of-domain-name

Comment: This is the correct answer if you created a Wordpress site using the Cloud Launcher feature of Google Cloud.  The Wordpress and Site URLs are set to the IP Address upon creation and once the domain has propagated you will need to update.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me,

GCP set IP Address as site URL when you deploy WordPress on google cloud.

Please change it to your domain name,

> WordPress Admin Panel >> Settings >> Site URL (& WordPress URL as
> well) >> add your domain name into textbox

Attached is the image for your reference.
[image: setting wordpress site url]